# HBase column qualifier limits

Tags: database-design, nosql, hbase

This is the question's setup:

I'm working in a project using HBase to store information about books availability. One of the queries I need to answer (and the one that will happen most of the time) is: Give me all the available books in a range of dates. To solve that I came up with a schema where, for every book ISBN, I have a column family with one qualifier for each day of the year and there I store how many books there are for that given day. This way I have 365 columns per row, and using ColumnRangeFilter I can return the book availability for any book (provided it's ISBN) in a given date range.

And this is the question itself:

Is there a limit in the amount of column qualifiers a row can have? Or at least a best practice for this? Because now I only have 365 column qualifiers per row, but if this project succeeds there's a chance to have around 10000 qualifiers per row. I like to know if this schema scales well for such scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there is actually not any limit of this kind, you must design your model keeping your use case into mind. IMHO, you are better off having wider rows if you need to do atomic operations across a broad range of data rather than having more number of rows with lesser number of columns. The advantage with this approach is that you can act atomically on several columns, as your use case demands. This will also allow readers, which are accessing a row concurrently, to see the entire update on that row.

But I see a possible downside with this approach. You might face some performance issues as a row will not be split across regions and hence will always be served by a single server putting extra load on that server. To avoid these kind of things you could probably think of having multiple column families, if it's possible in your case.

Comment: Thanks @Tariq for your answer. I agree with the first part, that's what I wanted to achieve: perform atomic operations per book. Regarding the second part of your answer, I didn't think about the splitting of regions, I will consider tunning my schema to avoid that scenario (loading a single server), perhaps creating a column family per month, or year, but that will requiere extra logic to process results in code. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Pleasure..If you have 1 CF/month, you will end up with too many CFs eventually(actually at the end of 1 year you'll be having 12 CFs), which is not good.

Comment: You are right. It seems I need to think a little more about this, but to start I can go with this design at least to make some tests. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no special limit of number of columns per row declared. Everything changes but at least people discuss 'millions of columns' cases which is definitely not your case. OK, there is limit of row size but it is far away from your numbers.

Here is another potential issue with 'too wide' rows. If you don't specify exact qualifiers any scan will result whole rows so you could get much more data than you actually need. Think about ranges like 'this month'. Again, do you really want to use slow intra-row scanning to get needed column inside row?

I'd recommend instead to think about better row key design.
Hope this will help you in some way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are right about too wide rows, but another thing I want from the described design is the atomicity HBase guarantees for row writting. From time to time I will need to perform updates to the amounts of books in existence for a given period of time, and with the given design I can make that atomically. Do you know a different way to solve this?

Comment: http://staltz.blogspot.com/2012/10/hacid-multi-row-transactions-in-hbase.html looks like some good point to start but as I know HBase itself does not provide any guarantee. The question is if you really need such operations to be atomic?

Comment: And here is another point for you: http://hadoop-hbase.blogspot.com/2012/02/limited-cross-row-transactions-in-hbase.html

Comment: Thanks @roman-nikitchenko. Regarding the atomic operations, hbase ensures atomicity only per row. I will read the link you share with me since it will be interesting to see how to achieve multi row transactions, perhaps that makes me rethink my schema :) Thanks again!